# Referring test groups in testng.xml

Tags: java, testng

Let's say I've annotated my test class with a test group in TestNG:

```
@Test(group='smoke-tests')
public class CheckEnvironmentTest {
...
}
```

Is there a way to refer to this group in testng.xml? Something like this (if it was implemented):

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Sequential" parallel="false" >
    <test-group ref="smoke-tests" />
  </test>

  <test name="ParallelGroup" parallel="classes"  >
    <test-group ref="regular-tests" />
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do something like this

```
<test name="sample">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="smoke-tests"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="CheckEnvironmentTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```